# Pgpool load-balancing vs. consistency

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, consistency

In what ways is consistency weakened when using pgpool-II load-balancing on Postgresql servers running streaming replication?

Obviously with asynchronous replication you can insert a row on the master server and then attempt (and fail) to select it from a slave. But let's assume synchronous replication is used (synchronous_commit and synchronous_standby_names options).

Are there still consistency issues to be considered?

I assume serializable transactions are always sent to the master server?